# Diagnose illness in dying watermelon vines

Tags: diseases, pests, pesticide, watermelon

It seemed to me that I had a nice health crop of water melon plants growing. Then I noticed the leafs developing brown spots and start to get brittle dry out, with some brown spots eventually turning white.

I'm guess that they must have been infected with some type of fungus. Can you identify?

Attached are images of the leaf at different stages of progression.

[image: Attached are images of the leaf at different stages of progression.]

Comment: This https://minnetonkaorchards.com/watermelon-diseases/#:~:text=Powdery%20mildew%20is%20one%20of,the%20leaves%2C%20not%20the%20fruit. may help you decide what the problem is. You may have more than one of the first three mentioned....

Comment: @Bamboo Yes, Disease(s) is what I was thinking. I haven't been able to match it yet via online articles.